# Integrating SQLite and remote RDBMS (MySQL?)

Tags: database, embedded-systems

I have an embedded system which currently uses either a local SQLite database or a remote MySQL instance.

Does anyone know any framework/tools commonly used for managing data integration between SQLite and the remote RDBMS?

What I am trying to achieve is an architecture where the embedded system uses a snapshot of the RDBMS (in SQLite) when out of network range and synchronises this local data to the remote RDBMS when it is accessible.  The idea is that many of these devices should be able to share data through the RDBMS, but still be capable of operating independently of it when out of reach of the network.

Any ideas/discussions around the topic would be gratefully received as well as recommendations of particular software implementations.  I am open to using other databases - SQLite & MySQL were selected entirely on cost.

Thanks!

More information:  The embedded devices run a Yocto Linux, the MySQL instance could be running under any OS.  Libraries in Python, C or C++ are going tobe the best fit for the rest of the application...